# make jquery wait before performing the next action

Tags: jquery, css

I have this fiddle.

on hover: second div must slide down, then third div.

when hover is lost: third div must slide up, then second div.

How can I do it?

**http://jsfiddle.net/sExNS/6/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".signincontainer").hover(function(){
      $(".myprofile").slideToggle(function(){
        $(".logout").slideToggle();
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the callback function, like that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".signincontainer").hover(function(){
    $(".myprofile").slideToggle(function(){
      $(".logout").slideToggle();});
  });
});
```

Check out that [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/sExNS/4/)

If you want the right order when mouse leaves, do it like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/sExNS/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".signincontainer").hover(function(){
      $(".myprofile").slideDown(function(){$(".logout").slideDown();});
  }, function(){
      $(".logout").slideUp(function(){$(".myprofile").slideUp();});
  });
});
```

Comment: @avrahamcool The second one breaks if the mouse leaves before the first slideDown (.myprofile) finishes -- it slides back up, while the second slideDown continues and .logout remains visible.

Can this be fixed to cancel the .logout slideDown when the mouse leaves?

Comment: @Michael you can you the `.stop()` function to finish previus animation before starting new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".myprofile").slideToggle(function () {
    $(".logout").slideToggle();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/sExNS/1/)

**UPDATE**

```
$('.signincontainer').hover(function () {
    $(".myprofile").slideToggle(function () {
        $(".logout").slideToggle();
    })
}, function () {
    $(".logout").slideToggle(function () {
        $(".myprofile").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/sExNS/12/)

Comment: @Anton the problem is now, it starts sliding up, even when the hover is not lost from container

Comment: @VedatMilor ah i see, change from mouseenter to hover instead

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".signincontainer").hover(function(){// work at mouse enter
          $(".myprofile").slideToggle(function(){
          $(".logout").slideToggle();
          });
      },function(){
           $(".logout").slideToggle(function(){// work at mouse out
          $(".myprofile").slideToggle();
          });
});
    });
```

See **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/sExNS/11/)**

reference **[slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)**  , **[hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)**

Comment: thanks. but when it slides up, it slides the second div at first

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sExNS/15/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".signincontainer").hover(
         function() {
             $(".myprofile").slideToggle(function () {
            $(".logout").slideToggle();
        });
        }, function() {
             $(".logout").slideToggle(function () {
            $(".myprofile").slideToggle();
            });
        }
    );

});
```